# Getting a 500 Internal Server error while posting data via Ajax to Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I previously posted this code for a different error, but I am getting a new error after that, so posting in a new post.

I have a basic Flask app, that logs user-agent strings and users local clock times in a database. My template file (`templates/home.html`) is as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type=text/javascript>
   $(document).ready(function () {
     console.log('Date Being Posted'); 
     var clock = new Date();
     console.log(JSON.stringify(clock));
       $.ajax({

            url:"/home",
            clock: JSON.stringify(clock),
            type:'POST',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
       });
    });

  </script>

  </head>
  <body>    
    <p>Your clock is being recorded on the loading of the webpage!</p>

    {% for user in users %}
    <p>{{user.clock}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

And my `main.py` is as follows:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from sqlalchemy import exc
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


project_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

#path to the database
database_file = "sqlite:///{}".format(os.path.join(project_dir, "userdatabase.db"))

app = Flask(__name__)

#indicate to the web application where the database will be stored
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = database_file

#initialize a connection to the database; use the db variable to interact with the databse
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

##define a model for the user

class User(db.Model):

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_agent = db.Column(db.String(1024), index=True)
    clock = db.Column(db.String(1024), index=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User-Agent: {}, Clock: {}".format(self.user_agent, self.clock)

@app.route("/home", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():

    if request.method == "POST":

        user_agent_received = request.headers.get('User-Agent')
        clock_received = request.json['clock']
        user = User(user_agent=user-agent_received, clock=clock_received)
        print (user)
        try:
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
        except exc.IntegrityError as e:
            db.session().rollback()

    users = User.query.all()

    return render_template("home.html", users=users)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Over here, I am:

a) initializing the database and creating a Model for the Users

b) receiving the clock times posted via ajax request inside `home.html` and storing it inside the database, while at the same time sending it to the `home.html` page to be displayed.

The database was created separately on the `Python3` Interpretor.

However, on the server, I am getting a `500 Internal Server` error. This error is displayed on the console, while I try to look inside Dev Tools to figure out the causes. I can't figure out why this could be the case, could anyone please help?

Comment: Also, in `user = User(user_agent=user-agent_received, clock=clock_received)` you've made a mistake `user-agent_received` should be `user_agent_received`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, ajax post in jquery has this structure:

```
       var clock={
          "key":value //say
       };



        $.ajax({
            url: 'home',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(clock),
            contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            // do stuff here
        })
        .fail(function(err) {
            // do stuff here
        })
        .always(function(info) {
            // do stuff here
        });
```

Now to access a posted JSON in flask, it's extremely simple use of `get_json()` method as:

```
@app.route("/home", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():

    if request.method == "POST":

        user_agent_received = request.get_json()
        # user_agent_received is now a regular 
        # python dictionary with same structure 
        # as input json sent from jQuery on client.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! It works now! I have a question, are the attributes `dataType` and `data` always necessary?

Comment: jQuery does make an intelligent guess when you provide data, but for POST it's always better to be sure of the data type you are sending.

Comment: Late addition: `data` is necessary. `dataType` can be guessed but don't let that happen.